# Error when starting jax-rs server

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am getting the following error when trying to start my web service locally

```
SEVERE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:172)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:264)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:246)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:117)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:92)
    at com.swiped.main.ServerStart.main(ServerStart.java:14)
```

My classes look as follows;

```
public class ExposedFunctions {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExposedFunctions.class);
    private DBFactoryController controller = new DBFactoryController();

    public ExposedFunctions(){
        if(controller!= null){
            controller.buildCache();
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/add/{username}/{password}/{email}/{firstname}/{lastname}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String register(@PathParam("username") String username, @PathParam("password") String password, @PathParam("email") String email, @PathParam("firstname") String firstname, @PathParam("lastname") String lastname) {
        if(StringUtilities.stringEmptyOrNull(username, password, email, firstname, lastname)){
            logger.error("String was null or empty when registering");
        }

        RegistrationStatus status = controller.register(username, password, email, firstname, lastname);
        return status.getValue();
    }
}
```

My web xml is as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>com.swiped.service</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.swiped.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And I kick it all off with my main class which looks as follows;

```
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create(BASE_URI);
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Press Enter to stop the server. ");
        System.in.read();
        server.stop(0);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have noticed that plenty of people have had a similar error however there is lots of varying advice given for individual circumstances making it hard for me to find a solution for this error. Does anyone see anything obviously wrong with my approach and if so please could you help me in resolving it?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate `ExposedFunctions` with `@Path`, too.

```
@Path("/")
public class ExposedFunctions {
```

**Edit:** The class is the root resource while the methods are sub resources. You must have both.